# Load Arbitrary Binary Files on HDFS in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

Scenario:

- There are 1000s of massive binary files on HDFS
- There is a `def decode(String localFilePath): Array[MyCustomType]` which can decode a file given its local path to its array of records

How can I use Scala spark to load these files in parallel and get a `RDD[MyCustomType]` in return?

PS. `decode` is a thrift decoder which gets a *local* file name loads a thrift file into memory as an array of records.

I think the missing puzzle here is downloading file from HDFS to a node and pass the local name to `decode`..

Comment: Might be vaguely and distantly related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635065/read-uncompressed-thrift-files-in-spark

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that you need to use spark's `PortableDataStream` to stream the binary data that is on HDFS to compute nodes.

```
val documentsRDD: RDD[Document] = sparkContext.binaryFiles("/data/path/on/hdfs")
  .flatMap { case (f: String, p: PortableDataStream) => {
    val stream: BufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(dis), 2048)
    // you can take it from here and do the rest. in my case I was dealing with thrift:
    val protocol: TBinaryProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(new TIOStreamTransport(stream))
  } 
}
```